# Electric panel update, should I do wiring too?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Ok the home was built in 1966 and the panel seems to be that old.  It's a 400 amp service coming in and no real issues other then the main a.c dimming lights here and their. But the panel is rusty (dropped from ceiling).  My electrician came out and I told him I'd like it off the roof and ran underground and just to replace what's their.  He said no problem gave me a rough quote of 3 to 4k.  So everything is good right? I forgot to ask about the wiring.  Just thinking back I see fabric wire amd new romex through the house just depends which room I'm looking at. Plenty of outlets in each room.  Should I replace the wiring?

Comment: Could you edit your question to post a picture of your panel?

Comment: This is a highly subjective question - you're asking our opinion on what you should do based on panel/wiring age.  This site is really intended for "HOW TO" not "what do you think" type questions.

Answer (score 3):

First, be very hands-on with panel selection and **Buy a *Huge* panel**. I'm talking *number of spaces*.  The point is to *make sure* you never come back asking: `"I need to add a circuit, but my panel is full."` *That is an expensive problem to fix, and So Very Cheap to prevent at panel-buying time.*

Panels come 16, 24, 30, 42 space. There's only a small difference in price per step, so max it out.  It's trivial cost on a $3000+ project.  Don't bother with 60 or 84 space panels, they're pricey.

Anyway, 400A installations are commonly done as *two* 200A main panels right next to each other, simply because that is vastly cheaper than a single 400A panel.  In that case, buy dual 42's.  (or 30's if you are impoverished).

---

Avoid double-stuff breakers - that's duplex, twin, tandem, GE's Qline 1/2" breakers, or any scheme to cram 2 breakers into a single breaker *space*.  They are a crutch to let them install a *way-too-small* panel. The fundamental problem with double-stuffs is **AFCIs and GFCIs are not available in double-stuff**, and those are required on near every circuit these days.

When a panel says "16 *space*/32 *circuit*, ignore the "circuit" number - that is presuming double-stuffs.

---

**Buy a quality panel**.  `Homeline` and `BR` aren't *junk*, but they aren't great either. Those same companies make much better panels called `QO` and `CH`. Some of us here have a bit of a love affair with `Siemens` (former Murray) and `GE` is superb, of course. They're all nearby in price range; the cheapies don't save much money at all.

Better panels *tend* to have spaces in multiples of 3, since they make variants of that panel which are 3-phase for industry.  Ford factories don't have a lot of BR panels.  (CH, yes.)

There's also a case to be made for using the family of panel you already own; so for instance if your old panel is full of perfectly good QO breakers, why not go with QO and reuse the breakers?

---

**That quote price**: Evaluating quotes is [not really what we do](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.  A huge portion of the total bill will be in the undergrounding the cable. That is serious work. So I'm not offended by the bill, I just can't tell you whether the next guy would charge $500 less.  I expect everyone will do the work to Code.  I also think what I say above about panel types says a lot about the electrician. The incremental cost difference from worst-case to best-case (from dual BR 16-space to dual Siemens 42-space) is only a couple hundred bucks, nothing on total project cost.

---

**The branch circuits**: I would not worry about those for now. There are *now* technological solutions for most deficiencies in the branch circuits, that can be handled right at the breaker panel.  Old wiring, aluminum wiring, boom AFCI. No grounds, boom GFCI. Sleep well that night.  Follow up at your leisure to make it perfect.

The only things I'd *really* be thinking about, branch-circuit-wise, is getting *enough* dedicated circuits into your kitchen so your wife never has to worry about tripping a breaker. Code now requires two 20A circuits just for countertop receptacles, and it's a really good idea to have your fridge *not on GFCI*, so a dedicated 1-socket circuit for the fridge is also called for.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing outmoded wiring in branch circuits in the house is a separate item from replacing the panel. It could be done at the same time, or equally well be done later. It would be costly to replace all of the old wiring and you might want to hold off and think about this.

But your local electrical inspection authority might require certain things to be done if you are having significant work done on the house wiring. Contact them for information. Changing the panel will require a permit and you will have to deal with them anyway.